# Cannot convert value to type "System.Int32"

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to import a csv file and select only columns where the number is above the a certain value (80):

```
import-csv 'C:\temp\t\xxxx.csv' | where-object {[int]$_.utilization -gt 80}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Cannot convert value "17 %" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At line:57 char:22
   +   import-csv 'C:\temp\t\xxxx.csv' | where-object {[int]$_.utilization -gt 80}
   +                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToInteger
```

`$_utilization` seems to be an Object

Any thoughts?

I tried to convert with `$util = [int]$_.utilization`, but I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Int32".
At line:3 char:1
  + $util = [int]$_.utilization
  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException
```

Comment: look at the first error.  it looks like one of the values that you are trying to convert to an integer is `17 %` which is not something that can be converted to an integer.  It would be a more complicated command but you could use `[System.Int32]::TryParse($_.utilization, [out] $intVar)` then if thats true, check if `$intVar -gt 80`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_.utilization` contains a *string*. To parse the numeric prefix as an integer, remove the space and percentage sign from the string first:

```
[int]($_.utilization -replace ' %$') -gt 80
```

Comment: this only works if the strings they're trying to check have no other non-int characters except for `" %"` in that order

Comment: @frankM_DN correct, although [much indicates that that is exactly the case here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74305754/inport-csv-with-sign-in-column-where-column-is-greater-or-equal-to-a-number) :)

Comment: Haha fair point I hadn't seen that question.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen it seems you have saved my Friday :) thank you so much! i have also tried to replace the empty space and % character, but seems that removing $ helped :) a really appreciate your help, once again thank you very much!

Comment: @scage007 Excellent to hear, you're most welcome! :) FWIW `-replace` is a regex operator, and in regex `$` is interpreted as a metacharacter meaning "end of string" - so `-replace ' %$'` basically means "replace a space and a percentage sign at the very end of the string". If you have more trailing whitespace after `%` you can do: `-replace '[\s%]+$'`